# Sharepoint OneDrive for Business and C# WPF Windows 7

Tags: development, sharepoint-addin, onedrive-for-business

I have a question and I would appreciate for your help.

I have WPF C# desktop application (windows 7) . And I want to connect to OneDrive For Business (SkyDrive Pro) account and to get the files from OneDriveForBusiness storage (we have corporate Office 365 account ).

If I understood correctly, I need to use Sharepoint API and REST GET command  for connect to  xxxxx@xxxx.onmicrosoft.com account?

But I can't understand how to do this.

At first, how to login? I need to add Browser component to my Desktop App?

Maybe somewhere c# Desktop samples are? With demonstrate basic operations: connect, get metadata, get files.

If Sharepoint API can't help me, tell me please, how can I do that? Which API I need to use?

Thanks for your consideration. It's really needed for me.

Answer (score 0):

First at all. You need to connect to SharePoint Online. You can make a console application to make your tests.

Depends of what you need.. you are going to need a tenant Administrator or not. 
Check these links that are going to help you.

[How to create a site collection in SP Online](http://www.vrdmn.com/2014/03/create-site-collections-with-csom-in.html)

[Find dlls](http://www.superedge.net/2014/03/where-is-microsoftonlinesharepointclien.html)